# Weird CSS Issue, Text & Images in footer section not visible

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, magento-1.9

I have an issue with text and images in footer section not being displayed. If I try to "select" with mouse, or when I click on the space and drag it, I can see its here... Text an images are on the place, its in the HTML. I tried absolute positioning, tried z-index, tried pretty much every CSS technique there is, I just cant figure out why its not being displayed properly.

Website is WordPress & Magento integration. On WordPress footer is displayed normally, but on Magento pages where I include WordPress header and footer. Header seems to be displayed nicely, and footer is there too, in HTML but on the browser visually all I see from footer is background.

See how the footer is displayed. Ive exhausted my whole knowledge and options, can you please help me, how to fix that, I cant even debug and see whats causing the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: animate.css is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the below style on the `kc-animated` div under `<footer>`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
  .kc-animated {
     opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Change that to 1 and it should appear fine. Try to override this value from your own style & it should work

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. Its 2 page html, for Magento and Wordpress as well, I guess I missed it somehow and didnt see that in the vast code. Thanks a million! One question, how did you find it, how did you investigate the issue, did you go through the blocks one by one or is there an easier way to debug this?

Comment: I could highlight the div but not "visible" so naturally its hidden probably via opacity/visibility. Then yes, investigate each div to find the right property. It just depends on how fast can you do this...Well simply put, its Developer tool + decades of experience :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking on the Hummingbird version at http://vitalmotion.3anglecorp.com/shop/hummingbird.html but as you say the text is invisible.

If you open the inspector in your browser and search for 'useful links' in the elements (this is one of the bits of text that is invisible) then the third-up parent div has class with setting for opacity as

```
.kc-animated {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Opacity = 0 means not visible. So this is the cause. If you turn that off or set to 1 you can see the text.

The cause is likely to be some of your animation code has a typo, of you didn't trigger the opacity to increase after some animation completed.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. Its 2 page html, for Magento and Wordpress as well, I guess I missed it somehow and didnt see that in the vast code. Thanks a million! One question, how did you find it, how did you investigate the issue, did you go through the blocks one by one or is there an easier way to debug this? Both answers are correct but Nikhil Answered couple mins earlier and I feel its fair to accept his answer, but I'll upvote your answer as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote - very fair of you. To find the issue I went to the site and then inspected the footer in chrome (right-click & inspect). Then I drilled down the structure div by div until I found some text that should be visible then went back up the parent divs from there looking for display=none, visibility=hidden, opacity=0 and any divs with height=0. As Nikhil says, just experience from many hours looking for such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make `opacity: 1` on `.kc-animated` class. See here: http://prntscr.com/d54m9e